# Is it possible to implement Paxos using unicast(Java) and Class C Addresses?

Tags: java, network-programming, multicast, paxos

My question is " **Is it possible to implement paxos-algorithm for distributed fault-tolerant applications using Class C Addressing without using Java based multicasting which uses Class D?** "

Actually, wherever I read about Paxos like [this one on Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-context-of-a-distributed-system-why-do-we-prefer-UDP-for-multicasting-than-TCP), they suggest that one should use UDP, which requires class D addressing.

My project in which I implemented a distributed application for file-server downloading used class C addresses in the range of `192.168.1.#`. Now, if I switch to class D address for multicast, I'll have to change my server addresses everywhere, which seems to me a daunting task!!

> NOTE :- I know that classful addressing is obsolete now, and we use
>   classless addressing everywhere. But, I used the term for
>   clarification of my IP-Addresses.

If your answer is NO, then please suggest how could I easily switch over to Multicasting without changing much of my code. Thanks.

Comment: Just read the article you linked: They actually suggest you use TCP since it is simpler to implement since you do not have to take care of the possible packet loss of UDP and the possible out of order arrival of UDP packages.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen-No, the main question is --- even if I use TCP, is it necessary to use multicast? Can't I use unicast? Please re-read my question!! Main question is how to keep using `Class C Address`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multicast you don't need to change your servers' addresses. It's a totally different concept. In the case of multicast addresses, the socket is bound to a class D address and in this case it is not an address assigned to a network interface but it's like a filter: you say "I want to receive all datagrams sent out (multicasted) with this destination address".

I googled for some examples of multicast sockets but you can get more:
http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~claypool/courses/4514-B99/samples/multicast.c
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/

Otherwise you will have to implement some kind of group membership with unicast.